# NPM crypto Diffie Hellman key exchange when user is offline

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I have the following code to generate a shared secret.

```
  
const crypto = require('crypto');

//Alice does it on her machine.
const alice = crypto.getDiffieHellman('modp15');
alice.generateKeys();

const aliceSecret = alice.computeSecret(bob.getPublicKey(), null, 'hex');

//Bob does it on his machine.
const bob = crypto.getDiffieHellman('modp15');
bob.generateKeys();

const bobSecret = bob.computeSecret(alice.getPublicKey(), null, 'hex');

//To verify both have generated the same secret
console.log(aliceSecret === bobSecret);
```

What I understand from this is bob and alice would generate public keys and exchange it with each other to build their own private key. The problem with this is, both the parties need to be online to do this if I'm not wrong. How do I proceed with making this independent of Bob and Alice being online to exchange each other's public? This is because I'm working on a chat application and Alice needs to create a thread with Bob even if he is not online.

PS: I'm running socket.IO for realtime communication and using MongoDB to store application data id that helps.

Comment: The example suggests that both parties need to be online. In the 'real world' both will generate their keys and store them for later usage. The e.g. alice will send her (unencrypted) public key to bob (or to the MongoDB) and bob will be able to pick the public key from alice). Same procedure with bob. When both parties have exchanged their public key they build the shared secred (aliceSecret == bobSecret) and the chat will be done with encrypted messages.

Comment: The question is better suited to crypto because it is more of a design question. A good application to look at for clues is Signal. Much care and thought has gone into that applications' key management.

Comment: @MichaelFehr in that case, if the public key is stored in database, some third party, say John, computes a private key from Bob's public key instead of Alice, does this mean he can establish communications and decrypt Alice's messages?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Looking at Signal Protocol, it does look like it's solved a lot of problems, thanks will get on using it.